# Click events not working in iPad Safari when used in zoom in

Tags: jquery, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

The iPad safari doesn't fire  click  event when zoomed in production environment.I have verified same code works in other deployment environment like-Dev or QA....Using Twitter bootstrap js ,jQuery and html5.....possible pointers

Comment: Refer this link you may get some idea: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759870/jquery-onclick-does-not-trigger-in-safari?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: what are the differences between your production and dev enviroments?

Comment: All environment are using weblogic 12c application server..basically same configuration...